# postgresql query to generate report with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a customer transaction table in postgresql db with the below columns

```
transactionId (primary)| customerId(int8)| transactionDate (timestamp)
1                        2                 2020-02-14
2                        3                 2020-01-08
3                        1                 2020-02-06
4                        2                 2020-02-13
5                        2                 2020-03-24
```

Need to build a query to create the report of the below

```
CustomerId| FirstTransaction| TotalTransactions| Transactions/Week| RecentTransactions
1           2020-02-06        1                  1                  2020-02-06
3           2020-01-08        1                  1                  2020-01-08
2           2020-02-13        3                  2                  2020-03-24
```

When the customer first started at first, total transactions, Frequency per week, Recency of last?
 and the report should consider(contain) last 3 months records only.

Comment: For transactions per week, do you go through the entire history of the customer and find out transactions for every week and then divide that by number of weeks that had transactions? For example, customer 1 may have had 5 transactions in the first week of Jan 2020 and no other transactions. Your database may have 50 weeks of transaction. So, would you say that transaction per week for customer 1 would be 5 transactions divided by 50 weeks = 0.1 transaction per week on an average? `OR` you just want transactions for the current week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sAg2bPsbeycy3TnLCzCyUP/2).

```
with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    count(*) over (partition by customerId) as totalTransactions,
    1 + floor((extract(day from transactionDate) - 1) / 7) as transactionsWeek
  from myTable
  where transactionDate >= '2020-01-01'
  and transactionDate <= '2020-03-31'
)

select
  customerId,
  min(transactionDate) as firstTransaction,
  max(totalTransactions) as totalTransactions,
  max(transactionDate) as recentTransactions,
  (ceil(avg(totalTransactions)/count(distinct transactionsWeek))::int) as "Transactions/Week"
from cte
group by
    customerId
order by
  customerId
```

Output:

```
| customerid | firsttransaction         | totaltransactions | recenttransactions       | Transactions/Week |
| ---------- | ------------------------ | ----------------- | ------------------------ | ----------------- |
| 1          | 2020-02-06               | 1                 | 2020-02-06               | 1                 |
| 2          | 2020-02-13               | 3                 | 2020-03-24               | 2                 |
| 3          | 2020-01-08               | 1                 | 2020-01-08               | 1                 |
```

for the last three months you can also use following in `where` condition

```
transactionDate >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'
```

Comment: transactionsWeek is incorrect for the customerId 3 (total transaction itself 1).

Comment: @Udhaya `2020-01-08` comes in second week of that month.

Comment: It's not about the first week or second week, Average transaction count per week. and also we need to consider the records of the last(past) 3 months only.